# Simple Java Confusion

Tags: java

I am working on A Java computing course, and I am stumped on what is causing an error here. I tried to research it but i seems difficult to search for this kind of error.

> ERROR: source_file.java:12: error: cannot find symbol 
>               double r = scan.nextDouble;
>                           ^  
>  symbol:   variable nextDouble  
>  location: variable scan of type Scanner

Code:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import static java.lang.System.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 class Rextester{


  public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Radius:");
     double r = scan.nextDouble;
     double circumference = (2 * 3.14 * r);
     double area = (r * r * 3.14);
     System.out.println("Circumference: " + circumference );
     System.out.println("Area :" + area );

    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, it says the character is doesn't recognize is the . between scan and nextDouble

Answer (score 9):

Methods require parenthesis

```
double r = scan.nextDouble();
                          ^
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick responses!!

Answer (score 3):

> ERROR: source_file.java:12: error: cannot find symbol double r =
>   scan.nextDouble;

this error means that you try to access a public element of the object that is hold in the variable `scan`.

What you want to call is not a public variable but the method `nextDouble()`

Therefor you must use `scan.nextDouble();` to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

change your line to  `double r = scan.nextDouble();` instead of `double r = scan.nextDouble`

Comment: The imports weren't missing, the code block was just messed up.

Answer (score 0):

change `scan.nextDouble` to `scan.nextDouble()`. It is a method and not field. So it requires brackets.

Answer (score 0):

nextDouble() is a method not property

so try:

```
double r = scan.nextDouble();
```

try to shorten your code:

```
  public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     double r = scan.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("Circumference: " + (2 * Math.PI * r));
     System.out.println("Area :" + (r * r * Math.PI));

    }
```

Comment: `nextDouble()` is a **method**, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Little side note, apart from

```
scan.nextDouble();
```

you should also use

```
Math.PI
```

instead of 3.14

---

Fixed code:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Rextester{


    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Radius:");
        double r = scan.nextDouble();
        double circumference = (2 * Math.PI * r);
        double area = (r * r * Math.PI);
        System.out.println("Circumference: " + circumference );
        System.out.println("Area :" + area );

    }
}
```